# How to solve this NFS unmunt problem?

Tags: ubuntu, nfs

I have working NFS (Networking File Sharing). It's server path will be mounted, but attempts to use `umount` are not working. It is getting some error.

```
$ sudo umount /nfs_server/    
/nfs_server was not found in /proc/mounts    
/nfs_server was not found in /proc/mounts
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: How did you mount `/nfs_server/`? If there is no entry in `/proc/mounts` is should be not mounted (anymore).

Comment: What does the output of `mount` show?

Comment: you answer your own quesiton, but even your answer is unclear

Comment: This is a genuine issue. Compare https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nfs-utils/+bug/974374 ; the description in the question is entirely accurate. (What's happening is `/etc/mtab` has a different format for the mount than `/proc/mounts`.)

Answer (score 1):

If the entry is not in `/proc/mounts` then I suspect your `umount` was in fact successful. When you attempt to run it again, you'll get the above messages from `umount`.

You can confirm what you have mounted using the `mount` command:

```
$ mount
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,seclabel,size=3977672k,nr_inodes=994418,mode=755)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
selinuxfs on /sys/fs/selinux type selinuxfs (rw,relatime)
```

Even after unmounting a mount, the directory `/nfs_server/` will persist. This is normal behavior, however the contents of the directory will be showing the contents from the system where the `mount` and `umount` commands were being run.

**NOTE:** When the mount is actively engaged from the NFS server, the contents of this directory will be supplied by that server instead.

Comment: I have this problem. The entry _is_ in `/proc/mounts`. It just seems umount fails at parsing it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the folder not supported, I find a solution using those two commands:

#### step 1:

```
$mount -o  mount -o soft,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192 common_share(server_path) to  /nfs_server/(client_path)
```

#### step 2:

```
$umount /nfs_server/(client_path)
```

Then you can unmount the path