# NFS umount fails to find directory in /proc/mounts

Tags: mount, nfs

When mounting an NFS share manually using `mount` and a path of the form `<domain/ip>:<path>/<path>` or `<domain/ip>:/<path>/<path>`, `umount` fails to find the path in `/proc/mounts`, despite the fact that the path is in fact listed in `/proc/mounts`.

This is the same problem as in this question: [How to solve this NFS unmunt problem?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157700/how-to-solve-this-nfs-unmunt-problem)

Steps to reproduce:

```
# mount --version
mount from util-linux 2.24.1 (libmount 2.24.0: debug, assert)
# mkdir mountpath
# mount 192.168.2.101:/devices mountpath
# umount mountpath
/home/.../mountpath was not found in /proc/mounts
# grep mountpath /proc/mounts
192.168.2.101://devices /home/.../mountpath nfs4 rw,[snip],addr=192.168.2.101 0 0
```

How can I unmount this mount?

Answer (score 1):

This problem arises because `mount` adds the mount to `/etc/mtab` with the path you specify on the command line, but in `/proc/mounts` it always appears with an additional slash.

To solve the problem, edit `/etc/mtab` to match the syntax in `/proc/mounts`.

To avoid the problem in the future, always mount SMB shares with the same syntax as `/proc/mounts/`: `192.168.2.101://devices`.

Compare also this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nfs-utils/+bug/974374